# Magento 1.9 Visibility : Orphaned

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog

In one of the project i saw  visibility as **orphaned** as far i know there is no by default functionality to set visibility as orphaned.

I trying to know how this option is created because when we set a product as orphaned its visible in frontend even in configurable associated product.

[image: magento product]

I found a plugin which override at /app/code/community/GPMD/SEOPack/Model/Product/Visibility.php

```
const VISIBILITY_ORPHANED = 5;
public function getVisibleInSiteIds()
    {
        return array(self::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH, self::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG, self::VISIBILITY_BOTH, self::VISIBILITY_ORPHANED);
    }
```

but i dont know how its affects the search functionality?

What is the use of **( in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Visibility.php )**

```
Do i need to add the  **VISIBILITY_ORPHANED** in these function 

     /**
         * Retrieve visible in search ids array
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function getVisibleInSearchIds()
        {
            return array(self::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH, self::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        }
     /**
         * Retrieve visible in site ids array
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function getVisibleInSiteIds()
        {
            return array(self::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH, self::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG, self::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that from one of the module new value for **Visibility** has been created using script.

You can see the visibility in **Visibility.php** file

> Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility

There are constants available for its value like

```
const VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE = 1;
const VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG = 2;
const VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH = 3;
const VISIBILITY_BOTH = 4;
```

Might be some one override this file and added custom visibility option type.

Comment: I found the file

Comment: Which file? Is that file override and added new option type inside it?

Comment: yes , at /app/code/community/GPMD/SEOPack/Model/Product/Visibility.php

Comment: Okay Great!! Now you can  do changes as per your requirement.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gmDGrgTs  here is the file which overrided, as far i know its just adding the new option here, but not able to trace how it affects the search behaviour

Comment: Visibilty used in Product collection to filter the data.

Comment: plz suggest the file for the same

Comment: Might be some has override Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List or made change in list.phtml file to override product collection.

Comment: Inside this file GPMD_SEOPack_Model_Product_Visibility 
there is function

public function getVisibleInSiteIds()
    {
        return array(self::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH, self::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG, self::VISIBILITY_BOTH, self::VISIBILITY_ORPHANED);
    }

Inside it mentioned self::VISIBILITY_ORPHANED so product will displayed aso if there are visibility set as self::VISIBILITY_ORPHANED.

Comment: but the products marked as orphaned are not visible at all , even by hitting the url directly in browser

Comment: sorry by mistake i edited your answer and i have no option to revert it.

Comment: Upvote the answer so it will be helpful to other also.